# Mac multiple app crashes - com.apple.HIToolbox?

Tags: mac

I am having trouble with multiple apps, mainly now with anything Adobe. I've deleted all I could from my system, but something tells me that leftover files from Adobe were not the cause.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x937ef18c CFEqual + 348
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x93852f67 __CFPasteboardCopyData + 3415
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x93852205 CFPasteboardCopyData + 53
3   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x944f20a1 isPrefsGetDefaultAsciiKeyboardLayout + 174
4   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x944f1abc isPrefsCreateCacheFromEnabledAndDefaultInputSources + 23
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x944f147d islGetInputSourceListWithAdditions + 143
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x944f13d1 TSMGetInputSourceCountWithFilteredAdditions + 44
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x944f07e2 TISCreateInputSourceList + 101
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x944f01c1 SyncHandwritingHotKey + 148
9   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x944ef128 _FirstEventTime + 1349
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

It may just be that you need to either update OSX or your Adobe apps. This has happened to me a few times and an update tends to do it.

Comment: Tried that.. tried combo update for Mac OS and adobe re-install from scratch. The only remedy so far is to start in safe mode and install updates there. The apps themselves work..